# Error in dots_list(...) : argument "label" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am building a shiny app and I am getting this error: Error in dots_list(...) : argument "label" is missing, with no default. I checked my UI to see whether I missed any label but I didn't find any and googled many times but didn't find any solution? Can anyone help? this is my UI & SERVER---

- UI

```
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shiny)
    library(htmltools)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Crop Area Allocation App"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
                     
                     numericInput("landsize","Please select Land Size in Bigha: ",
                                  min=1, max=1000, value=10, step=1),
                     
                     numericInput("invest","Please Write Investment Amount in Rs.: ",
                                  min=25000, max=5000000, value = 100000, step=25000),
                     
                     textInput("crop1","Please Write Name of First Crop: "),
                     
                     numericInput("rev1","Expected Revenue per Bigha for Crop1 in Rs.: ",
                                  min=1000, max=500000, value=20000, step=2000),
                     
                     numericInput("cos1","Expected Cost per Bigha for Crop1 in Rs.: ",
                                  min=1000, max=500000, value=15000, step=1000),
                     
                     textInput("crop2", "Please Write Name of Second Crop: "),
                     
                     numericInput("rev2","Expected Revenue per Bigha for Crop2 in Rs.: ",
                                  min=1000, max=500000, value=20000, step=2000),
                     
                     numericInput("cos2","Expected Cost per Bigha for Crop2 in Rs.: ",
                                  min=1000, max=500000, value=15000, step=1000),
                     br(),
                     actionButton("ClickMe","Click Me")
                     
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
        
            h4(strong("Land Size Mentioned by You in Bigha: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("lsize"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Investment Amount Mentioned by You in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("investment"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("You Selected following crops: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("cn1"),
            br(),
            textInput("cn2"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Revenue of Crop1 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("revenue1"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Cost of Crop1 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("cost1"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Profit for Crop1 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("Prof1"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Revenue of Crop2 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("revenue2"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Cost of Crop2 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("cost2"),
            br(),
            h4(strong("Profit for Crop2 Per Bigha in Rs.: ")),
            br(),
            textOutput("Prof2"),
            br()
        
    )
))
```

- SERVER

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    ls=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$landsize
        
    })
    
    output$lsize=renderText({paste(ls()," Bigha")})
    
    inv=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$invest
        
    })
    
    output$investment=renderText({paste("Rs. ",inv())})
    
    cr1=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$crop1
        
    })
    
    output$cn1=renderText({cr1()})
    
    rv1=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$rev1
        
    })
    
    output$revenue1=renderText({paste("Rs. ",rv1())})
    
    cs1=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$cos1
        
    })
    
    output$cost1=renderText({paste("Rs. ",cs1())})
    
    output$Prof1=renderText({paste("Rs. ",rv1()-cs1()," per Bigha")})
    
    cr2=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$crop2
        
    })
    
    output$cn2=renderText({cr2()})
    
    rv2=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$rev2
        
    })
    
    output$revenue2=renderText({paste("Rs. ",rv2())})
    
    cs2=eventReactive(input$ClickMe,{
        
        input$cos2
        
    })
    
    output$cost2=renderText({paste("Rs. ",cs2())})
    
    output$Prof2=renderText({paste("Rs. ",rv2()-cs2()," per Bigha")})
    
}
```

## Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In the `mainPanel()`, the statement `textIntput("cn2")` should be `textOutput("cn2")`.

Comment: I'm getting the same dots_list() error & cannot find the missing argument.

Comment: It's like @YBS says: either you give `textIntput("cn2")` a label if it really is supposed to be an input. Or you make it an output. In both cases the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this error too today, and discovered it was due to an error in the Actionbutton

Here it appears there may also be an inconsistency so try:

```
actionButton("Click Me","Click Me")
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Unfortunately, that does not remove the error. It would not explain it either, because the label of this action button is set.